# Is there HTML code for putting favicon icon for google searched websites?

Tags: html, favicon

[Here is a sample.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUvNH.jpg) When I search my website's name I can not see any icon there, it's the default, it must be a different relationship I guess like `<link href="./favicon.png" rel="???">`. So how to change it for Android & IOS chrome?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="icon" href="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/3565/3565518.png" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">
```

or use

`<link rel="icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

add the code in your head tag

Comment: That is not working. Please check the sample image file that you know what I mean.

Comment: @RobertMakeev replace the icon file link with your icon file path

Comment: please try to convert your icon file into ico file and place the full link path

Comment: I have tested both .png format and .ico format and also I tested all relations like ```rel="icon"```, ```rel="shortcut icon"``` and ```rel="apple-touch-icon"```.

Comment: It has to be another relation attribute I believe.

Comment: please try it first on your device. it takes some time to display. remove cache from your browser or reload your page by pressing ctrl+F5 if you can see the icon in your browser then dont worry. its alright. it will be udated soon by search engine

Comment: Hmph, my website has favicon of course already a long time, but I found out recently that is available when I search but I did not see any icon.

Comment: fav icon shows before title. if you can see your icon then its not an issue from your end